# Change default Google Map Marker Size

Tags: google-maps, marker

I want to change the size of the **default** Google Map Marker size.

Every other post about this topic shows how to change the size of a **custom** marker.

I tried with 'size' and 'scaledSize':

```
var newMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: marker.center,
  icon: { size: new google.maps.Size(60, 60) }
})
```

but nothing works.

Comment: You can't modify the default marker size.  You need to make a custom marker that uses the same icon and change the size of that.

Comment: You can check the documentation here on how to use custom marker icons: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/custom-markers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As geocodezip commented,
You can't modify the default marker size. You need to make a custom marker that uses the same icon and change the size of that.

Hope this helped others who were looking for an answer.
I don't why the question got down voted; I have not found any official documentation mentioning this anywhere till date.

Comment: Thanks for answering your question for others. It actually helped.